# Line spacing of MS Word Bibliography

Tags: xslt, ms-word, bibliography

I have a custom xsl biblopgraphy style (basically a copy from the APA6 builtin style with some minor tweaks to applease the gods of thesisrules at my uni). 
One thing that I can not seem to wrangle is the line-spacing. The style consistently uses a double spacing where I need a single spacing.

I have tried anything I could find online, the default setting for the 'Normal' style in the word-template is set to single. I have added an 'option' for 'line-spacing' set to single in the xsl, but I am not certain I placed it correctly, I am not even sure the xsl governs the paparagraph layout.

When I use the word interface to set the line spacing to single in the paragraph it gets overwritten on every refresh of the bibliography. My only other option is to keep changing it manually every time I submit a result.

Does anyone here know how I could permanently set the value to single spacing?

Comment: Have you tried altering line spacing in the Bibliography Style in the document itself? You can't just change the line spacing in the Bibliography field - as you've seen, Word will simply reset that at every refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment placed by Macropod I was able to fix my problem. I will document the solution here for posperity.

In the Ribbon (Home tab, Style section) not all styles are shown. Clicking on the small arrow in the section will open the Styles window, where you can set the option to show all styles. This magically rendered a style named "Bibliography" that allows changes to the paragraph, font and other attributes of the bibliography. There is a checkbox that allows you to make sure this style is shown on the Home tab, Style section.

So no programming or xsl options needed.